# How can I detect if a value is increasing?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I detect if a value is increasing in Unity with C#?
e.g if my `Position.x` value is rising or decreasing.

```
if(transform.position.x < temp.transform.position.x){
    ...
}
```

That isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the x-axis value and store it in a variable. Check in the `Update` function every frame if it changes then update that variable. If it changed, also update that variable.

```
float lastXVal;

void Start()
{
    lastXVal = transform.position.x;
}

// Use this for initialization
void Update()
{
    if (transform.position.x < lastXVal)
    {
        Debug.Log("Decreased!");
        //Update lastXVal
        lastXVal = transform.position.x;
    }

    else if (transform.position.x > lastXVal)
    {
        Debug.Log("Increased");

        //Update lastXVal
        lastXVal = transform.position.x;
    }
}
```

---

If you have to do this with many Object instances or also check more axis, their rotation and scale too, put the code inside [`transform.hasChanged`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-hasChanged.html). This will improve the performance as it will do all the checking when [`transform.hasChanged`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-hasChanged.html) is `true`.

```
void Update()
{
    if (transform.hasChanged)
    {
        if (transform.position.x < lastXVal)
        {
            Debug.Log("Decreased!");
            //Update lastXVal
            lastXVal = transform.position.x;
        }

        else if (transform.position.x > lastXVal)
        {
            Debug.Log("Increased");

            //Update lastXVal
            lastXVal = transform.position.x;
        }

        transform.hasChanged = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a method and call it each X seconds by using `InvokeRepeating` then check if your new position is lower or higher than its previous value after the check set the new value to the variable which holds your last position.

```
float lastpos;    
void Start()
{
lastpos = transform.position.x;
InvokeRepeating("checkPos", 0.01, 2.0);
}

void checkPos(){
if(transform.position.x < lastpos){
//decreasing 
}
else if(transform.position.x > lastpos){
//increasing
}
else {
//stayed the same
}
lastpos = transform.position.x;
}
```